# Using BASH - Find CSS block or definition and print to screen

Tags: regex, bash, unix, terminal

I have a number of .css files spread across some directories. I need to find those .css files, read them and if they contain a particular class definition, print it to the screen.

For example, im looking for ".ExampleClass" and it exists in /includes/css/MyStyle.css, i would want the shell command to print

```
.ExampleClass {
color: #ff0000;
}
```

Comment: And your question is...?

Comment: @David: The question is pretty clearly how to do this with a one-liner. @leonbloy: Presumably any language of one-liner (awk, sed, perl) is fine.

Comment: Any of the major dynamic languages (as well as shell) would be able to accomplish something like this.

Comment: @Jefromi: that may seem clear to you but it's not at all clear to me.

Comment: @David: Yes, it should've been explicitly asked. But there's a line that says "here is sample input and sample output" and "shell command"...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use find to filter on all *css* files and execute a sed script on those files printing lines, between two regular expressions:

```
find ${DIR} -type f -name "*.css" -exec sed -n '/\.ExampleClass.{/,/}/p' \{\} \+
```

Comment: 2 problems: sed is a stream editor so, like my solution, it doesn't handle multiline classes. And -exec, though it works, is very slow.  xargs is recommended for any kind of heavy lifting.

Comment: The exec+ variant is used, so the actual command line is built in the same way that xargs builds its command lines. 

exec+ doesn't require IPC via pipe so its actually  MORE efficient than using xargs.

Comment: It's good looking at everyone's solution, and I can learn from them all. I just grabbed this one and it's doing what I need for my project. Thank you

Comment: What do you mean it doesn't handle multiline classes? It looks to me like it should print everything including and between the first line matching `.ExampleClass.{` and `}`

Answer (score 0):

```
find /starting/directory -type f -name '*.css' | xargs -ti grep '\.ExampleClass' {}
```

will find all the css files, print the filename and search string and then print the results of the grep.  You could pipe the output through sed to remove any unnecessary text.

ETA: the regex needs work if we want to catch multiline expressions. Likely the EOL character should be set to `}` so that complete classes are considered one line.  If this were done, then piping the `find` to `perl -e` rather than `grep` would be more effective

Comment: That won't find multi-line blocks like the OP shows in the question. It will only find the first line.

Comment: Shouldn't that be grep '\.ExampleClass'?

Comment: @Christopher W. Allen-Poole: fixed

Answer (score 0):

Considering that the css file can have multiline class definitions, and that there can be several ocurrences in the same file, I'd bet perl is the way to go.

For example:

```
#input: css filename , and css class name without dot (in the example, ExampleClass)
my ($filen,$classn) = @ARGV;  
my $out = findclassuse($filen,$classn);
# print filename and result if non empty
print ("===== $filen : ==== \n" . $out . "\n") if ($out); 

sub findclassuse {
    my ($filename,$classname) = @_;
    my $output = "";
    open(my $fh, '<', $filename) or die $!;
    $/ = undef; # so that i read the full file content
    my $css  = <$fh>;
    $css =~ s#/\*.*?\*/# #g; # strip out comments
    close $fh;
    while($css =~ /([^}{]*\.$classname\b.*?{.*?})/gs) {
        $output .= "\n\n"  . $1;
    }
    return $output;
}
```

But this is not 100% foolproof, there remains some issues with comments, and the css parsing is surely not perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you never do anything weird, like putting the opening brace on a separate line, or putting an unindented (nested) closing brace before the intended one, you can do this:

```
sed -n '/\.ExampleClass *{/,/^}/p' *.css
```

And if the files are all over a directory structure:

```
find . -name *.css | xargs sed ...
```

Comment: Or the closing brace on the same line as the class name and opening brace (see my answer).

Answer (score 0):

This version handles multi-line blocks as well as blocks on a single line:

```
sed -n '/^[[:space:]]*\.ExampleClass[[:space:]]*{/{p;q}; /^[[:space:]]*\.ExampleClass[[:space:]]*{/,/}/p'
```

Examples:

```
foo { bar }
```

or

```
foo {
        bar
}
```

Comment: +1; definitely more robust than my answer, though possibly a little less practical for a one-off. Wheeeeeeeeeee, sed.